# Spark writing multiple files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes with different filter conditions I need to write both dataframes to hdfs same folder. How should I write both dataframes in one hugs folder.

Comment: Can’t you use append mode ? If both dataframe  schema is same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one single dataframe with the `union` transformation:

```
scala> val firstDF = List((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF("a","b","c")
firstDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 1 more field]

scala> firstDF.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+


scala> val secondDF = List((7,8,9),(10,11,12)).toDF("a","b","c")
secondDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 1 more field]

scala> secondDF.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  7|  8|  9|
| 10| 11| 12|
+---+---+---+


scala> val thirdDF = firstDF.union(secondDF)
thirdDF: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [a: int, b: int ... 1 more field]

scala> thirdDF.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
|  7|  8|  9|
| 10| 11| 12|
+---+---+---+
```

Then you can write it on the HDFS folder with the serialization format that you prefer.

Comment: If I want firstDF and secondDF both as  different file?

Comment: @jaggu just save firstDF to one folder and secondDF to another.

Comment: Can't we save both in same folder

Comment: @jaggu not in HDFS, because in HDFS inside every folder, single files are splitted to many nodes. So the base entity in HDFS is the folder.

Comment: @jaggu you can try using filename as a partition column. Write the firstDF with partition1 and secondDF as partition2.. guess that should work..